# Enter GPG passphrase with Zenity GUI enviroment

Tags: gui, gnupg, zenity, pgp

I am working about a Zenity GUI based GPG application. But I have a problem with that. GPG ask passphrase for encryption in terminal with this command `gpg -c $FILE`. However users must enter their passwords in Zenity box. Is there any helper program (like SUDO_ASKPASS variable) for Zenity?

How can I use `zenity --password` with above expression? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to do this with pure Zenity, but if you just want the user to input the password in a GUI box, add the following line to the file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` (create it if it does not exist already):

```
use-agent
```

Answer (score -1):

```
gpg -q --batch --passphrase=$(zenity --password) --decrypt
```

Comment: That minus looks very interesting. Sure I've answered correctly.